# find : /home/user/.local/share/gvfs-metadata : Permission Denied

Tags: permissions, sudo, find

When I type a command like `find / -name ??.conf` the output includes a lot of directories such as:

```
find : /home/simmer/.local/share/gvfs-metadata : Permission Denied
```

I don't get the desired result.

But if I use the same command with `sudo`

```
sudo find : /home/simmer/.local/share/gvfs-metadata
```

Then it shows the expected result.

Why do I need `sudo` privileges for this?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be getting that error, as the directory should be owned by you. I guess you have been [running graphical applications with `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications).

While logged in as yourself, correct the ownership (please always be careful when using `chown` with `sudo`).

```
sudo chown -R $USER: ~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata
```

Now you will not need `sudo` to search this directory.

In general, permission errors with `find` occur because you don't have read permission on the directory, which is the case for many system directories owned by root. You can use `sudo find` (be very careful before adding and actions to the command) or if you don't want to search as root, just discard the errors to de-clutter results by appending `2>/dev/null` to your command...

```
find /some/path -some_test some_condition 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `find` command is executed by a non-superuser it will not be able to access files and directories that are not owned by the user or if the permissions "r,w,x" have not be granted to that user. If you want to check this, type

```
ls -l /home/simmer/.local/share/gvfs-metadata
```

This command should return something like:

```
drwx------  2 simmer simmer 12288 Jun  8 17:39 gvfs-metadata
```

The first column represents the permissions set by the owners of the file or directory.
The third and fourth columns represent the owner and group of the file/folder respectively.

If you are not the owner or if you do not have sufficient permission as indicated by the first column, the `find` program cannot access them. However, using the `sudo` command elevates your privileges and thus as the `find` command is now executed by the superuser the directory and its sub-directories can now be accessed.

Comment: Also as @Zanna mentioned you should not be getting that error.  It should be owned by you

Comment: @Zanna I've only started to write answers on stack-exchange and so I'm not very familiar with the etiquette. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: :) thanks for editing. Looks great now. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu & Stack Exchange